# Attributes for private functions

Tags: pattern-matching, attributes

I am not sure if what I want to do can be done, but I thought to ask anyway.

**Note:** I already have in hand a workaround, I was just wondering for the power/simplicity that Mathematica may provide.

**Problem:** Suppose that I have in hand a polynomial in `x, y, z` and only products between `x,, z` and `y, z` occur, e.g.

`p = Pi x*z + Zeta[9] x^2*z + 123/7 z + 1/2 x + 5 y + 9/2 y*z + 3 y^5*z + 1/Pi* z^4`,

where I put some random constant coefficients in front of every term.

Now suppose, I have a homemade function that only executes "stuff" on numerical/numbers such as `Zeta[3]` or `19/2`. If I apply that function (e.g. `myF`) to `p` (`myF /@ p`) then it doesn't do "the job" because it can't handle the variables `x,y,z`.

Is there a way when I do `myF /@ p` to actually get

```
myF /@ p = myF[Pi] x*z + myF[Zeta[9]] x^2*z + myF[123/7] z + myF[1/2] x + myF[5] y + myF[9/2] y*z + myF[3] y^5*z + myF[1/Pi]* z^4
```

I know that the build in function `N`, has attribute `NHoldAll` and this is how it performs a similar to the problem, job.

**Comment:** No I will not give you more information (!) about the function `myF` because I want this to be as generic as it gets. If it has a solution, it is nice to be known and applied to any kind of "home-brewed" function since I can think of a big class of functions that would a enjoy such an attribute.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you already seen `Distribute[]`?

Comment: Would you care to elaborate, possibly with a small snippet? Thank you.

Comment: You did not operate on the number `2` in `x^2` in the second term. I suppose you mean to operate only on the numerical coefficients?  Might nonnumerical coefficients arise? Are the polynomials always expanded as in the example? I suppose the coefficient zero should be mapped to zero, not `myF[0]`?

Comment: Further, what about the coeffiicient `1`?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. That's the thing, I don't want to bother on what are the possible cases for `0,1`. I just want the function to be able to "pick up" the constants in front of the polynomials and do what the functions wants... Yes the exponents should stay as they are, otherwise `expr/.h_NumberQ:>myF[h]` does the job, but wrongly.

Comment: The reason that @MichaelE2 is asking these follow-up questions is: how is Mathematica to know what are coefficients and what are variables in the polynomial? How would Mathematica know that `Zeta[9]` is a coefficient, and not a variable $\zeta_9$?

Comment: That's exactly the question :) !

Comment: "I just want the function to be able to 'pick up' the constants in front of the polynomials..." -- And I was taught in school that the constant in front of `x^2` was to be treated as a `1`.  Which way do you want it, `x^2` becomes `myF[1] x^2` or it remains `x^2`?

Comment: Well, I set up the problem in a generic way so `x^2` should be `myF[1]` but this is trivial to resolve even if it is needed to stay as `x^2` since it's one pattern matching rule to apply on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps either

```
Fold[#1.{x, y, z} + #2 &, 
 Function[c, If[c == 0 || c == 1, c, myF[c]], Listable]@
  Reverse@CoefficientArrays[p, {x, y, z}]]
```

or

```
FromCoefficientRules[
 Normal[myF /@ Association@CoefficientRules[p, {x, y, z}]],
 {x, y, z}]
```

*[Update: Changed first code to leave `1` (as well as `0`) alone; unsure if the comment is saying that's what's desired. Otherwise, I would appreciate an example where the above fails.]*

Comment: Ok I just tried it and it works. It is a neat solution, thank you :). If you are kind enough, perhaps you could provide me with some clarifications: Why the `Reverse`? What's its purpose?

Comment: @hal `CoefficientArrays[]` returns the coefficients as a list of arrays according to the degree, starting with the constant coefficient and ending with highest-degree terms. The polynomial is constructed from the coefficients using a multivariate form of [Horner's rule](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HornersRule.html) starting from the highest-degree coefficients. (So `Reverse` puts the highest-degree coefficient first.)